# Equivalent of Visual Studio's Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down shortcut in JetBrains Rider

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Does Rider support the move caret to next/prior occurrence of the identifier like Visual Studio has with Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down? All I found is Ctrl+F3 but it does not have 2-way navigation and, as any other search functions, distract the attention from code editor to search controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JetBrains Rider (and other IntelliJ IDEA-based IDEs), you can highlight all usages of the identifier under caret via the "Highlight usages in File" action ("Alt+Shift+F11" in Visual Studio keymap; Ctrl+Shift+F7 in ReSharper/Default keymaps). Next, you can move caret to next/previous usage via F3/Shift+F3.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrey, probably this is the shortest path to navigate to the same symbol in Rider. But I am not sure I will get used to it - two shortcuts with F keys distract a lot. Basically I was looking for something like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6318-identifier-highlighter-reloaded that I have installed in Idea, but the plugin does not work in Rider.